# Cannot click button button when switching to mobile phone simulation device in f12

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am new to css pages. When I write an a tag with an href nested in it, it can be clicked in the computer simulation. But once it is switched to the mobile phone simulation, the click cannot jump. Why?

This is html：

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs/gh-pages/qrcode.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="page page5 hidden">
            <img class="page5mainbg fadeIn" />
            <img class="bg" src="img/background.png"/>
            <img class="main" src="img/mainHeading.png"/>
            <img class="dizhi" src="img/dizhi.png"/>
            <img class="red" src="img/red_wave.png"/>
            <img class="map" src="img/school_map_new.png"/>
            <a href="https://ditu.amap.com/search?query=%E8%8B%8F%E5%B7%9E%E5%9F%8E%E5%B8%82%E5%AD%A6%E9%99%A2%E7%BB%BC%E5%90%88%E6%A5%BC&city=320506&id=B0I6MCYD6X&query_type=IDQ" class="daohangmain">
                <button class="daohang">导航</button>
            </a>

            <span class="info1">联系电话：0512-66517351</span><br>
            <span class="info2">地址:江苏省苏州市吴中区吴中大道1188号</span>
            <div id="qrcode"></div>

        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TouchFunction.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animation.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcode.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my css：

```
/* new append page5 */
.page5 img {
    position: absolute;
}

.page5 .info1 {
    position: absolute;
}

.page5 .info2 {
    position: absolute;
}

.page5 .page5mainbg {
    background-color: #f42a1b;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.page5 .bg {
    width: 90%;
    right: 5%;
    top: 8%;
    height: 75%;
}

.page5 .main {
    width: 60%;
    right: 20%;
    top: 5%;
    height: 6%;
}

.page5 .dizhi{
    width: 60%;
    right: 20%;
    top: 5%;
    height: 6%;
}

.page5 .map {
    width: 70%;
    right: 15%;
    top: 15%;
    height: 30%;
}

.page5 .daohangmain {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    top: 41%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.page5 .red {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 51%;
    height: 55%;
}

.page5 .info1 {
    width: 50%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 46%;
}

.page5 .info2 {
    width: 76%;
    right: 9%;
    top: 51%;
}

.page5 #qrcode {
    position: absolute;
    right: 58%;
    top: 58%;
}
```

I use z-index: 99; But is not work...

Please tell me how to modify the css style so that the button link can be clicked on the mobile phone to jump.

Comment: Please put your HTML through a validator. You cannot have a button element as a child of an anchor (a) element.

Comment: anchor tags should not contain interactive elements. It's pretty odd to see a `<button>` nested inside a `<a>`. I can't say that's the problem you are experiencing but you have 2 main options there before doing anything else: 1. using `<a href="..." class="daohang">...</a>` 2. `<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='...'">...</button>`.